# Static UITableView appear disabled opaque alpha not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, alpha

I have a classic UITableViewController in an iOS 6.1 application. The table view is static and set in storyboard and it meant to represent configurable settings using UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark as ON/OFF switch. There is a section in TableView that disables another cell based on other setting. The cell is disabled with the following code:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.alpha = 0.4;
```

The code is working fine once the TableView is loaded.

**The problem is when TableView is loaded, the disabled cell code is not working correctly, because alpha setting in code does not work. UserInteractionEnabled property is working, but not the alpha setting.**

This is code that should disable UITableViewCell when the view is loaded.

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell)
    {
        ...

        if ([[self currentSettingForIndexPath:indexPath] isEqualToString:@"myDependencySetting"])
        {
            ...
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                cell.alpha = 0.4;

                NSLog(@"Disabling cell: %0.2f", cell.alpha);
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            cell.alpha = 1.0;
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Cell alpha: %0.2f", cell.alpha);

    return cell;
}
```

The code here is fairly simple, I ask the super for cell (since self is subclass of UITableViewController, it shouldn't be a problem), then configure the cell. If cell on current index path depends on another setting, I disable the cell (I stripped some other lines of code that are irrelevant).

The output reads:

```
...
Cell alpha: 1.00
...
Cell alpha: 1.00
Disabling cell: 0.40
Cell alpha: 0.40
Cell alpha 1.00
...
```

**So according to output the alpha property of the cell is set correctly.** But the cell alpha is not set, however the cell is not tappable because of userInteractionEnabled.

*The same code works for disabling the cell in tableView's delegate didSelectRowAtIndex.*

The question is: **Why and what could override the cell's alpha value?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I know it's two years down the road, but I grappled a bit with the same exact problem as you and stumbled across this question. I happen to be using iOS 8, but the problem seems the same: I've got a static table view with a couple of cells whose alpha I'd like to adjust on initial table view setup. Making these adjustments in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` did not work. Each cell adjusted showed on screen with an alpha of 1.0, although I was logging their alphas at 0 in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Since I was interested in adjusting all cells of a single section, I was able to obtain the desired functionality by including something along these lines in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)changeAlphaOfCells:(float)alpha
{
     for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ROWS_IN_SECTION; i++)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:SECTION_NUMBER]];
        cell.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

You'll need logic to determine which cells to adjust the alpha of in `viewWillAppear`, and retrieve them with `cellForRowAtIndexPath.` Not as elegant as a single line call in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant access the cell's alpha directly like that. Try this

EDIT:

```
UIColor *colorWithAlphaOfPointFour = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.4];

[[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithAlphaOfPointFour]];
[[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithAlphaOfPointFour]];
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithAlphaOfPointFour]];
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I cannot access cell's alpha like that? Because it works alright when I do it after the tableview is loaded, just not in the cellForIndexPath function. However the thing you suggested works, but it does not make the cell transparent, only the textLabel inside the content view. So it is not a good solution.

Comment: I would've thought you could access it just like you did, but if its not working then that would be next guess.  There might be a cell.background or something of the sort you can access.  Otherwise its going to be some weird issue with how you dequeue cells and reuse them

Comment: If this was an issue with dequeueing and reusing cells, setting alpha to every cell should be noticeable. But it is not. And I don't think there is much dequeueing with static table views.